# How to set default Font and Font Size in Tinymce3.0?

Tags: tinymce-3

Not able to change default font and font size. I have tried different methods as following.

1. content_style: "body { font-size: 14pt; font-family: Arial; }"
2. this.getDoc().body.style.fontSize = '14px';

[image: tinymce3.0 issue]

Answer (score 0):

I have done a workaround to fix this issue, Please find the following details.

Modified the following file and changed title from 'advanced.fontdefault' to 'Font'.
\tiny_mce\themes\advanced\editor_template.js

[image: tinymce default font title issue fixed]